# A question regarding Blender 2.78 and sculpt tool UI

Tags: sculpting

I was following a tutorial, created a UV sphere, drew a line with grease pencil and then used grease cut but it doesn't cut the sphere in two, instead it just draws a line across the sphere (Like adding a new ring).

I also notice I have no smooth option in my grease pencil settings even though I'm using the same add on version as they are.

I've tried both using scene and object in grease pencil settings.
Is this an incompatibility with 2.78 or am I doing something wrong and if so, what?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Blender.SE - for us to help, you should help too by adding a link to the tutorial you refer to and giving a name to the Addon you refer to. Keep people guessing and they might ignore your questions.

You are referring to the Sculpt Tool Addon? Does your UVsphere have enough geometry? Usually it fails when there are not enough edges. Try sub-divide your mesh a bit and try again...

[image]

Regarding your question about smoothing the grease stroke: You need to be in Edit Strokes first, then select your stroke for example with the box select - <kbd>B</kbd> key . You can bring up the menu with <kbd>D</kbd> & <kbd>E</kbd> and choosing smooth. The smooth function is used with the left mouse while the <kbd>E</kbd> key is held down...

[image]

***Update:*** I understand a bit more what you were asking. The Grease Pencil cutting is done in Object Mode - I am not aware it was ever done in Sculpt Mode. I see from an [old tutorial/review](http://cgjam.net/blog/sculpt-tools-ui-blender-addon-review/) that there was indeed a 'smooth' option under the Grease Pencil in Sculpt Tools. Perhaps it was part of [Kent Trammells additions](https://github.com/MadMinstrel/blender-sculpt-tools/issues/1) (?) As far as I know the Sculpt Tools Addon hasn't been updated for a few years and if it makes you feel better, I don't have the 'smooth' option referred to.

That said, one of the biggest additions in the latest Blender release is the 'new' Grease Pencil. As a lot of the functionality got moved around it does seem like overkill to even have the settings under the Sculpt Tools when the Grease Pencil has it own more robust menu...except 'Grease Cut'.

Comment: Yes it's the sculpt UI tool, the whole smooth thing was simply because they had that option shown but I did not (I was wondering if it was a symptom of the problem).

Comment: The tutorial I'm doing is the scifi helmet sculpting introduction from cgcookie and it seems that if I draw the grease pencil whilst in sculpt mode and then switch to object mode it then works as it should, even when I then draw the grease pencil in object mode afterwards, perhaps it's a bug or incompatibility on my end?
Either way, with a little fiddling around it seems to work now.

Thanks for taking out the time to answer, it's very much appreciated, I'm a total beginner and it's good to know there are people such as yourself willing to help!

Comment: Updated - see above.